# Python Patching Nested Function Calls

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I am trying to mock two methods within a single function call. Below I have the method `entry_point` which then calls `foo`, which in-turn calls `bar`.

I want to ensure that both `foo` and `bar` are called, and I also want to inspect their arguments to see what the types and values are of the passed arguments.

**`foo.py`**

```py
class MyClass:
    def entry_point(self):
        self.foo(x=2)

    def foo(self, x):
        self.bar(y=x*3)
    
    def bar(self, y):
        return y**2
```

**`test_foo.py`**

```py
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
from foo import MyClass

class TestMyClass(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_nested_patch(self):
        mc = MyClass()

        # I would like to find out what arguments are passed
        # in to both foo() and bar()
        with patch.object(mc, "foo") as mock1:
            with patch.object(mc, "bar") as mock2:
                mc.entry_point()
                # PASSES
                mock1.assert_called_once()
                # FAILS HERE: "bar" not called
                mock2.assert_called_once()

                # ADDITONAL: I want to see the function arguments
                _, kwargs1 = mock1.call_args
                _, kwargs2 = mock2.call_args
                self.assertEqual(kwargs1["x"], 2)
                self.assertEqual(kwargs2["y"], 6)
```

```
AssertionError: Expected 'bar' to have been called once. Called 0 times.
```

I have tried it a few different ways, but the above code seemed to be the cleanest way to explain my situation.

I recognize I could get around this by calling `mc.entry_point()` within two different (non-nested) patch context managers (one for `foo`, one for `bar`) but that is not as clean and doesn't really give me full control over the function calls.

Comment: Why do you care about the intermediate `foo()` method being called? If you refactor the class to call `bar()` directly in `entry_point()`, the tests will break. Tests are supposed to help you with refactoring - and therefore depend more on requirements and less on implementation details.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve really? This looks bad because you're coupling your tests to the implementation as described above by decorator-factory.

Comment: Well, yes; the mock version of `foo` *doesn't* call the mock version of `bar`, so that's what gets reported. The entire point of mocking is to *substitute* what happens internally with a placeholder, so that you can *skip* complicated internal logic and *isolate* your test away from that. If for some reason `foo` is an important part of the interface, then you can mock `foo` (and check for a call) when testing `entry_point`, and then *also test `foo`, mocking `bar`* (and checking for a call) that time. Otherwise, *there is no reason for test code to care* whether `foo` calls `bar`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies! I think I was looking at this problem too broadly, such that `foo` and `bar` are a single behavior that I want to test. You all make some great points, it seems that it would make more sense to have separate tests. One to test that `entry_point` calls `foo`, and another to test that `foo` calls `bar`. The reason I originally strayed away from this approach is b/c the function arguments that actually get passed into these methods are a bit more involved, but manageable.